# A broadcast receiver is it always working?

Tags: android, broadcast

I'm developping a SIP application and i have a broadcast receiver to receive incoming calls.
My question: when i quit the application i see that the process of my app is working but don't receive incoming calls. Is it normal ? why it's not listening to incoming calls and catch them to the the ALertDialog that i coded it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly like your scenario, I hope this helps..

I've recently implemented a broadcast listener to intercept new outgoing calls to a specific number.  I've tested a successful interception even after using Advanced Task Killer to kill off the app.  It still intercepted the broadcast 100% of the time.

Comment: @Kon: How did you that please ? did you implemented a service ? or just some code in the brodcast receiver ?

Comment: Yes, you have to extend the BroadcastReceiver class.  And add an appropriate intent filter for your receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

Comment: @Kon: By what i extend it please ? and what is the appropriate intent filter to add ?

Comment: You'll have to do some research on all this on your own.  Here's a link that may help as well:  http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-ii-intent-receivers/

Comment: @Kon: so i have to register the receiver and have to add <action> name in the <intent-filter> . Correct ?

Comment: @Kon: other question please: if i do this i'll have the application's UI launched when receiving a call ?